# Question on valuation axioms - Relating to $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: absolute-value, valuation-theory

In an earlier thread, I asked if there was a standard generalization of the absolute  value of $\mathbb{C}$ that could be placed on a field, but might not take values in $R_{\geq 0}$. What somebody suggested was that I look into the theory of valuations, and so I went to the Wikipedia page. The definition it gives is as follows.

Let $(G, \cdot, \geq)$ be an abelian, totally ordered group. Define the ordered monoid $G \cup \{ O \}$ by
\begin{align*}
(\forall  g \in G) & (g \geq O) , \\
(\forall g \in G) & (Og = gO = O) .
\end{align*}
Now let $k$ be a field. Then a map $v : k \to G \cup \{ O \}$ is a *valuation* on $k$ if
\begin{align*}
v(a) = O & \iff a = 0 , \\
(\forall a, b \in k) & v(ab) = v(a)v(b) , \\
(\forall a, b \in k) & v(a + b) \leq \max \{ v(a) , v(b) \}.
\end{align*}

My issue is that I understood these valuations to be a generalization of the standard idea of putting an absolute value on $\mathbb{C}$ (and its subfields). However, the absolute value would fail the last of these axioms, i.e. $| 1 + 1 | = 2 \not \leq \max \{ |1| , |1| \}$. Am I misreading this? Or is this whole valuation thing just completely different than absolute value?

Comment: This definition captures as a special case the non-Archimedean absolute values, e.g. the ones you complete with respect to to get the $p$-adics. If you replace the third axiom with $v(a + b) \le v(a) + v(b)$ you get a notion that captures the usual absolute value on $\mathbb{C}$ as a special case, but now the target should be some kind of ordered ring. Anyway, ultimately it depends on what you want to do.

Comment: A valuation is not an absolute value. Each leads to the other but they are not the same thing.

Comment: @LuisGomezSanchez - What do you mean, "each leads to the other"?

Comment: Indeed this couldn't generalize the typical absolute value. What this induces is an ultrametric space, as opposed to a metric space. The triangle inequality is replaced by the inequality you ask about, sometimes called the strong triangle inequality. Some interesting things happen in ultrametric spaces, such as all triangles are isosceles, and every point enclosed by a circumference is the center!

Comment: @AJY: For example if you have a valuation $v$ then for $\alpha>1$  the function $|x|_{\alpha}$ = $\alpha^{-v(x)}$ defines an absolute value. And if you have an non-Archimedean absolute value and $\alpha>1$ then the function $v(x)=-log|x|_{\alpha}$ defines a valuation.

Comment: Is there any way to get the "classical" absolute value from here without making $G$ a ring?

Comment: A ring structure is essentially for making polynomial operations (sum, multiplication and distributivity). Without this, I don´t know how conciliate with axioms of absolute values. However astonishing generalizatios are not absent in mathematics.....

Comment: @LuisGomezSanchez - Okay, another question: If I have a non-Archimedian valuation $v$ taking values in my ordered monoid $G \cup \{ O \}$, is it generally true that I can find an order-preserving group homomorphism $\phi: G \to \mathbb{R}^{+}$, which I can then extend via $\phi(O) = 0$, i.e. that I can turn a $G \cup \{ O \}$-valued valuation $v$ into a $\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$-valued valuation $\phi(v)$?

Comment: @AJY: I don't know, sorry.